# BSOD Memory Management

Tags: memory, bsod, memory-management, dump

While I was playing overwatch, I got several BSOD.

I already tryed Memory Diagnostic and sfc/scannow with no luck! 
I attach some dump of the BSOD!

Thanks for the future answers!

[DUMP](https://mega.nz/#F!CkpkiLiI!6cbrzuPIXHphIEgyIFZoNg)

Comment: Have you used windbg to determine the cause of the crash?

Comment: One of your crashes was due to the graphics driver crashing. Have you updated your graphics drivers lately? The rest seem to be memory related. I would run Memtest86 to make sure your RAM passes without errors.

Comment: Those cases are quite hard to troubleshoot but are very often caused by compatibility issues between the graphics driver and the game.  Many games require patches (fixes) to work with certain graphics adapters, so you should check the game's support forum.

Answer (score 0):

[According to WIndbg](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-15-WinDbg-Bugchecks), the crash is hardware related and causes that 1 Bit is corrupted:

```
STACK_TEXT:  
00 nt!KeBugCheckEx
01 nt! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'
02 nt!MiDeleteVad
03 nt!MmCleanProcessAddressSpace
04 nt!PspRundownSingleProcess
05 nt!PspExitThread
06 nt!KiSchedulerApcTerminate
07 nt!KiDeliverApc
08 nt!KiInitiateUserApc
09 nt!KiSystemServiceExit
0a 0x0


SYMBOL_NAME:  ONE_BIT

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: hardware

IMAGE_NAME:  memory_corruption

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  0

IMAGE_VERSION:  

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  MEMORY_CORRUPTION_ONE_BIT

BUCKET_ID:  MEMORY_CORRUPTION_ONE_BIT

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  MEMORY_CORRUPTION_ONE_BIT
```

I see you use BIOS/UEFI Versin 1.0,

```
BiosVersion = P1.00
BiosReleaseDate = 07/01/2015
BaseBoardManufacturer = ASRock
BaseBoardProduct = Z170 Extreme4+
```

so using Corsair RAM (CMK16GX4M2A2133C13) with the old BIOS can cause issues. [Update to at least BIOS/UEFI version 2.30](http://www.asrock.com/mb/Intel/Z170%20Extreme4+/index.us.asp?cat=Download&os=BIOS), which has DRAM fixes.

If you still get crashes, check the RAM with memtest86+ for errors.

Comment: Hi guys! Checked with memtest last night and no errors! 
Now i will try to update the Bios! Thanks!

Comment: does the BIOS update fix it?

Comment: Cause of work, didnt have the chance to test it! I will update you guys in this weekend! :)

Comment: any update? Is the PC now stable?